Can I use cloud quantum computing now to solve perturbation theory equations?
I am a physics student and I understand C++ programming. I would like to try quantum cloud computing for my master's thesis.
Can I write an algorithm or software code and apply it to quantum perturbation theory?
How hard would it be to learn that?

Hi, welcome to QCSE. Could you provide some more details on the sort of problems you are trying to solve?

For example, you have a potential equation and you want to find the energy and wave equation for it.
